# Get byte value as a string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the actual value of a byte instead of its conversion to an ASCII string.

I have a byte with the value 0x00000073 how do I get 73 as a string value instead of it being converted to the string value of 115?

Comment: If you have `byte b = 115;` then you want `string s = b.ToString("X");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andrew Morton is spot on.

If you have byte b = 115; then you want string s = b.ToString("X");

Comment: For better readability use code formatting. Put `\`` backticks before and after the code. Type \`byte b = 115;\` to get `byte b = 115;`